# Sql Server 2005 - Returning GUID from SP

Tags: sql-server

I need to return newly created GUID from Stored procedure for each time i make a call.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourSproc
@guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
AS
SET @guid = NEWID()
```

And an example of calling it...

```
DECLARE @temp UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
EXEC YourSproc @temp OUTPUT
SELECT @temp
```